# Bootstrap modal DOM element not available in Angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

On opening Bootstrap dialog its HTML is placed in the DOM root right below < body >.

[image: Here it is]

The target element is outside of the Angular root component and that's a reason why the next querying in unit test gets no result.

```js
const modalContent: HTMLElement 
   = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.modal-content');
```

Is there a way to write component DOM test with modal window implemented in such way? Or to be more concrete how can I query here for HTML of opened modal window in order to test its content then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose this one should work:

```js
const modalContent: HTMLElement = document.body.querySelector('.modal-content');
```

Comment: saved my day with your answer, thank you!