# Angular Unit Test - Mat Dialog element is always null

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I am trying to fix my unit test which fails since I added a dialog to my component.

The scenario is, that when a button is clicked, a warning dialog should appear which asks if the process should go further or may the user wants to return without any changes.

This is the code snippet from my component method:

```
onDoSomething(): void {
    if (someConfition) {
        doSomething();
    } else {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
        dialogRef.componentInstance.dialogText = this.WARNING_TEXT;
        dialogRef.componentInstance.isConfirmDialog = true;
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(rp => {
            if (rp.confirmed) {
                doA();
            } else {
                doB();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my dialog-component.html:

```
<div>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>{{ dialogText }}</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isConfirmDialog; else warningDialog" mat-dialog-actions align="center">
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()" cdkFocusInitial>OK</button>
</div>
<ng-template #warningDialog>
    <div mat-dialog-actions align="center">
        <button id="okButton" mat-button (click)="onDoConfirm()" cdkFocusInitial>OK</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Abbrechen</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

and the ts file...:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-dialog',
templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
```

})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

```
public dialogText;

public isConfirmDialog;

constructor(
    protected dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}

onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close({ confirmed: false });
}

onDoConfirm(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close({ confirmed: true });
}
```

}

When I run my unit test, the dialog is visible in the browser:
[image]

But when I triy to click it within my unit tets, the button is never found no matter what query I write.

This is my test:

```
fit('test my method', async () => {
    selectANnumber();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const headerCheckbox = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('tbody tr:not(.emptyCol) checkbox');
    expect(headerCheckbox).toBeTruthy();
    const checkbox = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('tbody tr:not(.emptyCol) td checkbox');
    expect(checkbox).toBeTruthy();
    const rowCheckbox = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input'))[1].nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    expect(rowCheckbox.checked).toBeFalse();
    rowCheckbox.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    const myButton = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button')[1];
    myButton.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const okButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#okButton')).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    okButton.click();


    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    const card = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.mat-card');
    expect(card).toBeTruthy();
    expect(card[0].innerText.trim()).toEqual('My job has been successfully done');
});
```

Can it be that the dialog content is not rendered into the DOM or something like that?
I have no clue left...

P.S. When I click the button manually in the browser, then it happens exactly what it should be. So it is not the funktionality, but the test whats does not work...

Any suggestions? I would really appreciate...
Thank you!

---

**EDIT**

Test result:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

Altought:

[image]

[image]

---

SOLUTION:

After checking millions of articles, I have found this one which helped me:

[Bootstrap modal DOM element not available in Angular unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65581410/bootstrap-modal-dom-element-not-available-in-angular-unit-test)

My dialog container was not within fixture.debugElement, neither within fixture nativeElement, so I had to refer my button as follows:

```
const okButton = document.body.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('button#okButton');
```

Comment: @zzzz thanks, but this did not help be with my test..

Comment: Share the test result / error message

Comment: @zzzz edited my post

Comment: do a``console.log(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#okButton')))``

Comment: @zzzz okButton: null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234926/discussion-between-dorcsi-and-zzzz).

Comment: Any posibility you could create a StackBlitz demonstrating the problem?(Could fork from [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xlgengxvmba?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)).